# How to check if the string contains only slash symbol in it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to check if the string contains only / symbol in it ? The string may have more than one / symbols with white spaces in between. In such cases i want to consider that the string is empty.

Comment: Could you clarify "In such cases I want to consider that the string is empty"? Do you want to match any of these: "/", "//", "/ /", " //", etc.? Strings with any combination of "/" and whitespace?

Comment: Ok. The scenario is, The value is saved to database by concatenating multiple strings with "/" So when i retrieve the same value, the string is not empty as it contains    "/            /         /         /" when the contacting values are empty during saving. I do not want to show empty spaces with slashes while showing in web page.

Comment: why not just replace any occurrence of slashes and spaces to `""`. Eg: `if text.Replace("/", "").Replace(" ", "") = "" then ' it's empty`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c# the answer would be:

```cs
if (yourText.Count(x => (x != '/') && (x != ' ')) > 0)
{
    //not empty
}
```

Basicly: "if the count of all the characters which are not "/" or a space is greater than 0"

I have not done VB in a while, but translating it should not be hard. You could just do for-loop approach

```vb
Dim isEmpty as Boolean = true;
For (Dim i as Integer = 0 to yourText.Length - 1)
    If (yourText[i] <> "/"C And yourText[i] <> " "C) Then
        isEmpty = false;
    End If
Next
```

Again, I am doing this completely from memory, so excuse me if my syntax is off. Correct my code if I have an error.